# Magento 2: How to test my extension with Magento Marketplace EQP?

Tags: magento2, extensions, third-party-module, marketplace

How can I run the Magento Marketplace EQP in my current installation that has my extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official set of rules and sniffs for PHP CodeSniffer tool - https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp

More details - https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Extension_Quality_Program_Overview.pdf

Comment: FYI, magento link is dead(404).